# Is there a wallet for different cryptocurrencies

Tags: wallet

For a person who has different amount of different cryptocurrencies it is actually annoying to use many clients. Right now just Bitcoin data is more than 15 GB, litecoin 1.5 GB and so on.

Is there any wallet which incorporates many wallets? Is it possible?

Comment: I have the exact same inconvenience. Would be really interested to hear about an answer. Else, it might be a very interesting project to develop: a multi-currency virtual wallet...

Comment: That's technically possible. After all a wallet is just a file with  data and keys plus some specific services. Anyways, I don't know single online / offline wallet service that is capable of storing multiple crypto-currencies.

Comment: what worries me is that to make payment you need to be connected to other bitcoin/litecoin/othercoin network and most probably need to have all the information about the blocks (or partial information)

Comment: Would be interesting to know what is the reason for downvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [UFASoft Coin](http://ufasoft.com/coin/). Which is a multi currency client and miner. Also it's open source.

The supported currencies are.

- Bitcoin - BTC
- Bitcoin-testnet
- Namecoin - NMC
- Litecoin - LTC
- PPCoin - PPC
- NovaCoin - NVC
- TerraCoin - TRC

This will essentially keep all your wallets in one application, so no more have 6 different wallets and clients. Then forgetting to start certain ones.

Just a side note regarding the performance of mining directly from the program: I have found it to be slower, around 10-30% slower than other miners.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. As far as I understood you are using it by yourself? Performance for mining is not an issue, but what about the size of downloading block chains? Does it download all of them?

Comment: Quick question: if I already have both the bitcoin and litecoin wallets and then install this UFASoft program... is there a way to move all the blockchain files from both to UfaSoft's folder? I certainly wouldn't want it to download YET AGAIN the files :P

Comment: @SalvadorDali: Yes as far as I understand it downloads multiple blockchains (as their different)

Comment: @JoePineda: As far as I know, there is no way to import an existing blockchain. As UFASoft stores the blockchain in a compressed format.