# Are there clients that manage several alts?

Tags: client, alternatives

E.g. a desktop client that can manage, in a unified UI, Bitcoin, Namecoin, Litecoin, PPCoin...?

Comment: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=264219.0

Comment: Doesn't this fall under the close reason `"Questions seeking product or service recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve."`?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - my situation - I am writing a product that deals with various alt currencies. My problem - how to deal with various alt currencies (receive, send) using a simple API. Stack Exchange close reasons are beyond me, if the consensus decides to close it, so be it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a wallet for different cryptocurrencies](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11115/is-there-a-wallet-for-different-cryptocurrencies)

Comment: I don't see this question as seeking a product recommendation; it's asking whether a product exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ufasoft open source client can manage different alt-coins, most of them with same private keys.

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=58821.0

PD: be careful, some users have reported malware in Ufasoft mining software.