# Can i store multiple crypto currencies in one wallet?

Tags: wallet, currencies, storage

Is it possible to make a wallet for BTC and store LTC and NMC or other coins in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a software wallet to do this, but if you want it for cold storage, you can definitely create addresses for almost all the cryptocurrencies from a raw 256 bit private key. This allows you to just securely store the 256 bit key rather than the individual wallet files for multiple cryptocoins.

You can do this by:

1. Creating a 256 private key of 64 hex (0-9,A-F) digits
2. Open brainwallet.org and go to the "Generator" tab and select "secret exponent"
3. Paste your 64 hex digits into the "Secret Exponent" text box.
4. Select the coin type in the top right corner and the coins private key and address will be shown in the "Private Key" and "Address" areas.

As an example, the 256 bit private key A5F308EB5553464AD377C68D16CDB85F3C8D63CABAC8017BE6D9D9A43F7F0CDF is the following addresses:

- BTC (Private): 5K5NXzAa7PE5irZFc9Va6eAN4zPfd2E9MBcrt1ea8j225ix6wpC
- BTC (Address): 18S5Czkk3pp8vSwVsS8fD28HLxea6JcVc
- LTC (Private): 6vP717i71ogxCET77yHXt2wY2Tx8ppgB7s22bCfbrBLdmZvbD5f
- LTC (Address): LKMPLRJapi4sPj96g1RRwE5tVZKviuvMxS
- NMC (Private): 74A5i3WERWPrjWmvkHmXhKLdgvR1Re3gGRJTZoRBpoNBk1JL8RM
- NMC (Address): MvhoGrVjfRvNfThSmgkhsjB31aMhYnd5qs

Note that this is somewhat insecure as if someone knows the coin private key for one of the addresses, they can directly convert the coin private key back to the raw private key.

Also if you import a private key into a wallet program (eg: bitcoind), be aware that they may send change to new addresses.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like it was not a good idea to try it with multiple currencies in one wallet @.@ Then i must find how i can secure my ufasoft files then it would be working.

Comment: Ufasoft sent me the following on my question about the wallets they use "Private keys shared between all currencies in the Ufasoft Coin. But they have different address string for different currencies. Internally they are the same"

Answer (score 6):

[**Coinomi Universal HD Wallet**](http://coinomi.com/) will do exactly what you're looking for.

[**Coinomi**](http://coinomi.com/) is a very secure and lightweight, universal, open-source HD wallet for Bitcoin and many altcoins. At the moment the supported coins are:

- Bitcoin
- Dogecoin
- Litecoin
- Peercoin
- Darkcoin
- Reddcoin
- NuBits
- NuShares
- Blackcoin
- Feathercoin
- Rubycoin
- Digitalcoin
- Cannacoin

with more integrations on the way.

Comment: Coinomi indeed rocks. Still waiting for the Desktop version and the iPhone version, but I think it's the nicest of all of these.

Comment: Not open source anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a real wallet program that does it, but if you look for a web wallet, [VirCurEx](https://vircurex.com/) might be something.

It's an exchange for different crypto-currencies and so you also have a web wallet for each of them.

Comment: I dont want to have all my money on a web wallet where it could be stolen all at once when something bad happens. I want to store 3-5 differenct coins but without installing several tools that hold a single coin type. When i find out where the Ufasoft Coin software stores my wallets i could go with it.

Comment: I can understand that you prefer not to. But as I said, there currently is no wallet that can fulfil your needs.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a related question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11115/is-there-a-wallet-for-different-cryptocurrencies) but it only describes UFASoft Coin, which seems like a windows-only desktop application. If you're looking for a cloud solution I've found [HolyTransaction](https://holytransaction.com/) to work pretty good.

Answer (score -1):

Yes and no, the wallet software for each is an independent piece of software built by the community around that single cryptocurrency. It's possible that third party developers have/will develop a multi-currency digital wallet, to date all I have found is http://ufasoft.com/coin/, but I have not used it personally.

Comment: My problem with the ufasoft solution is, that i can not find any information where my coins are really stored. My idea was to use my bitcoin public/private key on another currency.
It would be fine when someone can give me infos on where ufasoft stores its infos.